# Thread called more times while trying to exit from a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, exit

I wrote a program which creates two threads, each of which calls a function which basically prints and then call `exit()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *myfunc(void* myvar)
{
    printf("Hello SO\n");
    exit(1);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1 , thread2;
    char *msg1 = "First Thread";
    char *msg2 = "Second Thread";
    int ret1, ret2;

    ret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, myfunc, (void*)msg1);
    ret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, myfunc, (void*)msg2);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following sets of output:

## Output 1 (Desirable):

`Hello SO`

## Output 2 (Desirable):

`Hello SO`

`Hello SO`

## Output 3 (Undesirable as thread calls the functions two times only):

`Hello SO`

`Hello SO`

`Hello SO`

Please help me with figuring out the solution to output-3.
Note : Everything works fine if I remove the `exit()`.

Comment: Please refer for documentation of `exit ()`: *Calling this function destroys all objects with static duration:* **A program with multiple threads running shall not call exit (see quick_exit for a similar function that does not affect static objects)** *.*

Comment: @AlexLop. What is meant by destroys all program with static duration ? Isn't every program of static duration ?

Comment: Is this on LInux with glibc?

Comment: Yes this is on linux glibc.

Comment: @udhy How are testing this? In script or redirect the output to a file?

Comment: How does that matter? I'm printing onto the `stdout`. Steps : `gcc name.c  -lpthread` and then running the executable `./a.out`.

Comment: It matters because I suspect it's a buffering issue. So with `\n` in the printf, it's not possible to observe what you see if it's attached to a console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96556/discussion-between-udhy-and-blue-moon).

Comment: Are you calling `exit()` be intention to end the whole process including all its threads? If not, that is if you only want to end one specific thread, then either just leave the thread function be calling return, or call `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: No I call that with the intention to end the whole process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to a bug in the glibc implementation of `exit()` which is unexplained output -- more output than the number of threads.
When the process exits by calling `exit()`, it has to flush all streams, including stdout, to write all unwritten output from buffer. 
So it's possible that there is a "more" than what you wanted in `stdout`'s buffer.

`stdout` is usually line buffer when attached to a terminal device. So I suspect you either don't have `\n` in the printf or do some sort of output redrection (such as pipe/rediecting to a file).

IIRC, glibc implementers didn't fix it and as a fix, you can call `setbuf(stdout, 0);` at the start of main() in order to disable the buffering. You can also call `pthread_exit()` instead of calling `exit()`.
Remember `exit()` terminates the whole process. Besides, `exit()` is not thread-safe. So you can only call it safely when you know there's no race condition. To terminate just the thread, call `pthread_exit()` or simply return from the thread function.

I'll link the glibc bug report when I find it.

Comment: @EOF In the Linux man page of [exit()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html).

Comment: Ah, thank you. That's a much more recent version than the manpages on my system. Curiously, even on that site, `exit()` is not on the list of thread-unsafe functions in `pthreads(7)`.